# How I turn multiple columns into two columns?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, transpose, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I have a sales SpreadSheet that is divided in columns per month and I need to turn the months into columns with the sales values.

I've made an example sheet

[Example Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yGkl3QFb6pKaWTo-JJ7MR2j9O_I-RUXB_hzqga_XOUM/edit?usp=sharing)

I have the data in this model:

[image]

and I need to turn it into this model:

[image]

There is a way to do this with formulas or script?

I've tried to use Pivot Table and Transpose but didn't work as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({"PRODUCT"\ "MONTHS"\ "SALES"; 
 SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(
 IF(B2:G9<>""; "♠"&A2:A9&"♦"&B1:G1&"♦"&B2:G9; );;999^99));;999^99); "♠")); "♦")})
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Hello! Thank you! It worked fine, but can you please explain how this work? I didn't get it

Comment: sure, `IF` range B2:G9 is not empty we append to that non empty value also A column and row 1 (the header row). we use unique symbols in between like ♦♠ but it could be any symbol you wish ☺♀♪♫♥♣... understand these symbols as separator marks for `SPLIT` function. then with `QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(` we join all cells into one single cell. 999^99 also doesn't matter. could be any number 1000, 23564, 999999 - it just needs to be huge (more than all rows you have). and then the combo of `SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(` cuts it into pieces giving you the final desired result